# Why keyboard is not showing in Listview Edittext?

Tags: listview, keyboard, android-edittext, swipe

I have used one library for swipe from left to right in listview but in the listview one edittext is there and after click on edittext keyboard is not showing.

```
holderGroups.edit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") 
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                im.showSoftInput(holderGroups.edit, 0);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.performClick();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Please go through my code and suggest me some solution.